# Centering selected point on map using OpenLayers, Geoext and ExtJs

Tags: openlayers-2, geoext, ext-js

I am using Openlayers + Geoext1 + ExtJs3.4.

I have an ExtJs combobox next to the map with several points of the map that are provided from a PostGIS database through Php/XmlHttprequest.

At the same time I have a map with all points containing their respective attributes.

I need to select a point from the list and then this point must be searched on the map an centered on it.

How should I proceed with this case?

I am thinking about relating combobox valuefield with map feature id or perhaps retrieving coordinates directly from the database and centering the map on this coordinates.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest getting the geometry from the database and using that to center the point in the map.

To center it you need to do:

```
var pointCenter = new OpenLayers.LonLat(//here the way you get the geometry);
map.setCenter(pointCenter);
```

If you have a combo box, you could use a function in a handler to call some urls pointing to your php script, or simply add that combo to a geoext formpanel or featurestore to get the geometry data.